# where in clause mysql sort by relevance

Tags: mysql, sorting, where-clause

I have tables named news and tags_news. Given a news id I have to output relevant articles based upon tags. So I have a list of tags like google,facebook, I am using the following query

```
select 
  t2.title,
  t2.content,
  t2.id
from
  tags_news as t1
  left join news as t2 on t2.id=t1.news 
where t1.tag in ('facebook','google');
```

everything is working fine, but the articles are returned in order of their id. I want to have articles which have more matches with the given tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right.

Try the following:

```
select 
t2.title,
t2.content,
t2.id,
count(*) as numberOfTagsRelatedToTheNews
from
tags_news as t1
left join news as t2 on t2.id=t1.news 
where t1.tag in ('facebook','google')
group by t2.title
order by numberOfTagsRelatedToTheNews desc
```

Is this what you're looking for? Ask, if you have any questions to this answer.